# The Integral of $\int \sin(ax) \cos(ax) dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

What is the integral of:
$$I=\int \sin(ax) \cos(ax) dx$$

My approach is down below.  I have attempted the problem and posted it as an answer.  I did the problem using trigonometric substitution.
$$u=ax$$
$$\frac{du}a=dx$$
$$\frac{1}a\int\sin u \cos u \ du$$
$$g=\sin u$$
$$dg = \cos u \ du$$ 
$$\frac{1}a\int g\ dg$$
$$I=\frac{1}a\frac{\sin^2ax}{2}+C$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin(ax) \cos(ax)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2ax)$$

Answer (score 4):

$$u=ax$$
$$\frac{du}a=dx$$
$$\frac{1}a\int\sin u \cos u \ du$$
$$g=\sin u$$
$$dg = \cos u \ du$$ 
$$\frac{1}a\int g\ dg$$
$$I=\frac{1}a\frac{\sin^2ax}{2}+C$$

Comment: Looks like someone enjoys the long road ;-)